# Why does the number of rows in my data frame increase?

Tags: r, dataframe

I started out with a data frame that has 10 rows, and based on some condition, I populate a column. By the time, I reach the end of the loop, I see that I have more rows in my data frame.

Please see code below for reproducing.

```
col1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
col2 = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
df = data.frame(col1,col2)
bucket = c(2,4,6,8,10)

cat(paste("Number of rows at start == ",nrow(df)))

df$newcol = NULL
for(i in 1:5)
{
 if(i == 1)
 {
  df[1:bucket[1],"newcol"] = "val1"
  cat(paste("from 1 to",bucket[1],"\n"))
 }else
 {
  df[bucket[i-1]+1:bucket[i],"newcol"] = paste0("val",i)
  cat(paste("from ",bucket[i-1]+1,"to",bucket[i],"\n"))
 }

 cat(paste(nrow(df),"\n\n"))
}

cat(paste("Number of rows at end == ",nrow(df)))
```

At the end, my data frame looks as follows

```
   col1 col2 newcol
1     1    2   val1
2     1    2   val1
3     1    2   val2
4     1    2   val2
5     1    2   val3
6     1    2   val3
7     1    2   val4
8     1    2   val4
9     1    2   val5
10    1    2   val5
11   NA   NA   val5
12   NA   NA   val5
13   NA   NA   val5
14   NA   NA   val5
15   NA   NA   val5
16   NA   NA   val5
17   NA   NA   val5
18   NA   NA   val5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change

```
df[bucket[i-1]+1:bucket[i],"newcol"] = paste0("val",i)
```

to

```
df[(bucket[i-1]+1):bucket[i],"newcol"] = paste0("val",i)
```

in the loop and and run it to get

```
 df
 #  col1 col2 newcol
 #1     1    2   val1
 #2     1    2   val1
 #3     1    2   val2
 #4     1    2   val2
 #5     1    2   val3
 #6     1    2   val3
 #7     1    2   val4
 #8     1    2   val4
 #9     1    2   val5
 #10    1    2   val5
```

As an example

```
bucket[2-1]+1 : bucket[2]
#[1] 3 4 5 6
```

Due to the operator precedence, it is doing

```
bucket[2-1]+(1:bucket[2])
#[1] 3 4 5 6
```

To rectify it, we can separate the parts with the braces

```
(bucket[2-1]+1):bucket[2]
#[1] 3 4
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer why but rather how to do better. Can you elaborate on why this happens? I don't see that.

Comment: @martin I did explained with a small example about the operator precedence.

Comment: Ah, I have missed that part, my provider probably swallowed it ;), thanks.